# Powershell: 'else' is not recognized if written in a new line

Tags: powershell

When I run an `if/else` Construct like this in my Powershell Command line

```
if ($foo) {
    Write-Host "foo!"
}
else {
    Write-Host "bar!"
}
```

it throws an error:

```
else: The term 'else' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

[image]

But when I run it like this:

```
if ($foo) {
    Write-Host "foo!"
} else {
    Write-Host "bar!"
}
```

**... it works fine!**

```
PS> bar!
```

It seems, that Powershell interprets `else` as a standalone command. Which is wrong, of course (`else` always needs an `if` or `elseif` before).

**Fun Fact:** In `Function`, `ForEach` operations or executed as `ps1`. it behaves as desired.

Does anyone know how to get rid of this? This annoying behavior is on all Powershell Versions (5, 7, Core) and Platforms identical.

Comment: Which version of Windows and/or PowerShell are you using? Pasting commands is generally not a problem in newer versions that ship with `PSReadLine`, but the paste behavior might change if you're using a different terminal than the default console host

Comment: Is there some weird character we cannot see after the closing bracket of the `if` ? I'm on PowerShell 5.1 on Win10 Pro 21H1 and cannot reproduce that.

Comment: It would work ok in a script.

Comment: @js2010 Thats what I already mentioned!

Answer (score 3):

Technically an `if` statement without an `else` is a valid expression so the *PowerShell terminal* does not know that YOU want to extend that expression to the next line with an `else`. And so it interprets the `else` as a new statement altogether, hence the error.

Of course the behaviour in a file is different as Powershell knows where the start and end of a file is so it can parse it all, instead of line by line. In this example if you want PowerShell to expect more expression then end the line with a backtick `` "`" ``

```
if ($foo) { # open bracket so Powershell knows to continue expecting input
    Write-Host "foo!"
} ` # end of bracket so this could potentially be the end of the expression, 
    # but with a backtick it knows to continue processing!
else {
    Write-Host "bar!"
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Powershell is interpreting the `}` as the end of the statement, so also interprets the `else` as the start of a new statement.

You can solve this by putting a tick `` ` `` after the `}` to indicate that the line should not terminate.

So,

```
if ($foo) {
    
    Write-Host "foo!"
} ` #notice the tick (`) which instructs powershell not to consider this the end of the current statement
else {
    Write-Host "bar!"
}
```